# start, monitor and define script of SageMaker processing job from local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am looking at [this](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker_processing/scikit_learn_data_processing_and_model_evaluation/scikit_learn_data_processing_and_model_evaluation.ipynb), which makes all sense. Let us focus on this bit of code:

```
from sagemaker.processing import ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput

sklearn_processor.run(
    code="preprocessing.py",
    inputs=[
        ProcessingInput(source="s3://your-bucket/path/to/your/data", destination="/opt/ml/processing/input"),
    ],
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="train_data", source="/opt/ml/processing/train"),
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="test_data", source="/opt/ml/processing/test"),
    ],
    arguments=["--train-test-split-ratio", "0.2"],
)

preprocessing_job_description = sklearn_processor.jobs[-1].describe()
```

Here preprocessing.py has to be obviously in the cloud. I am curious, could one also put scripts into an S3 bucket and trigger the job remotely. I can easily to this with hyper parameter optimisation, which does not require dedicated scripts though as I use an OOTB training image.

In this case I can fire off the job like so:

```
tuning_job_name = "amazing-hpo-job-" + strftime("%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())

smclient = boto3.Session().client("sagemaker")
smclient.create_hyper_parameter_tuning_job(
    HyperParameterTuningJobName=tuning_job_name,
    HyperParameterTuningJobConfig=tuning_job_config,
    TrainingJobDefinition=training_job_definition
)
```

and then monitor the job's progress:

```
smclient = boto3.Session().client("sagemaker")

tuning_job_result = smclient.describe_hyper_parameter_tuning_job(
    HyperParameterTuningJobName=tuning_job_name
)

status = tuning_job_result["HyperParameterTuningJobStatus"]
if status != "Completed":
    print("Reminder: the tuning job has not been completed.")

job_count = tuning_job_result["TrainingJobStatusCounters"]["Completed"]
print("%d training jobs have completed" % job_count)

objective = tuning_job_result["HyperParameterTuningJobConfig"]["HyperParameterTuningJobObjective"]
is_minimize = objective["Type"] != "Maximize"
objective_name = objective["MetricName"]

if tuning_job_result.get("BestTrainingJob", None):
    print("Best model found so far:")
    pprint(tuning_job_result["BestTrainingJob"])
else:
    print("No training jobs have reported results yet.")
```

I would think starting and monitoring a SageMaker processing job from a local machine should be possible as with an HPO job but what about the script(s)? Ideally I would like to develop and test them locally and the run remotely. Hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure I understand the comparison to a Tuning Job.

Based on what you have described, in this case the `preprocessing.py` is actually stored locally. The SageMaker SDK will upload it to S3 for the remote Processing Job to access it. I suggest launching the Job and then taking a look at the inputs in the SageMaker Console.

If you wanted to test the Processing Job locally you can do so using [Local Mode](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#local-mode). This will basically imitate the Job locally which aids in debugging the script before kicking off a remote Processing Job. Kindly note docker is required to make use of Local Mode.

Example code for local mode:

```
from sagemaker.local import LocalSession
from sagemaker.processing import ScriptProcessor, ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput

sagemaker_session = LocalSession()
sagemaker_session.config = {'local': {'local_code': True}}

# For local training a dummy role will be sufficient
role = 'arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-20200101T000001'

processor = ScriptProcessor(command=['python3'],
                    image_uri='sagemaker-scikit-learn-processing-local',
                    role=role,
                    instance_count=1,
                    instance_type='local')

processor.run(code='processing_script.py',
                    inputs=[ProcessingInput(
                        source='./input_data/',
                        destination='/opt/ml/processing/input_data/')],
                    outputs=[ProcessingOutput(
                        output_name='word_count_data',
                        source='/opt/ml/processing/processed_data/')],
                    arguments=['job-type', 'word-count']
                    )

preprocessing_job_description = processor.jobs[-1].describe()
output_config = preprocessing_job_description['ProcessingOutputConfig']

print(output_config)

for output in output_config['Outputs']:
    if output['OutputName'] == 'word_count_data':
        word_count_data_file = output['S3Output']['S3Uri']

print('Output file is located on: {}'.format(word_count_data_file))
```

Comment: thanks - so are you saying that processing_script.py is local and will be uploaded? I take it source='./input_data/ can also be an S3 bucket? Otherwise, which "machine" is the folder relative to? Thanks!

Comment: Correct code can be a local file relative to your local machine or a path to S3. The SDK would upload it to S3 on your behalf if its local. 

Same behaviour with source_dir. 
```
If source_dir is an S3 URI, it must point to a tar.gz file. 
```
https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.processing.FrameworkProcessor.run

Comment: cool thanks. do not thin this is possible. will try and then (possibly) accept

Comment: just had the time to check. actually there is %%writefile as well see: https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker_processing/scikit_learn_data_processing_and_model_evaluation/scikit_learn_data_processing_and_model_evaluation.ipynb this is amazing thanks!